# downloading an image with angular's $http from amazon's s3 return bad request(400)

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, https, angular-http

I'm writing an angularjs 1.5.0 application.

In this application i need to use `$http` to fetch image data to a blob.

i used the following code in my angular js controller:

```
$http({
            url : 'https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/my-images/thumb_0000000001.jpg',
            method : 'GET',
            params : {},
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : undefined,
            },
            responseType: "blob"
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
```

my website is at https://myalcoholist.com

I enabled cors in my s3 bucket using Bucket Explorer with the following parameters:

```
AllowedOrigin https://myalcoholist.com
AllowedHeader *
AllowedMethod GET
```

before settings the cors , i would get a preflight request error. after enabling cors I get

```
GET https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/my-images/thumb_0000000001.jpg 400 (Bad Request)
```

the pre-flight request, the OPTIONS method is sent and succeeds.

```
Request URL:https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/my-images/thumb_0000000001.jpg
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:54.231.114.146:443
```

but then the GET Request fails.

I tried to put an image on https://myalcoholist.com and then to try to get it with $http request and I got no errors. it seems that only trying to download from amazon's s3 is causing problems and I have no idea why!

the ACL is set for read. and browsing that file in the browser works.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Image isn't being sent as blob, it's sent as image. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Probably want to use canvas api not ajax for this depending on use case

Comment: Or set server to force download

Comment: i want to download and display a base64 content of the image.

Comment: can do that with created image element and canvas api

Comment: i don't want to change the image md5sum and i'm sure that it will remove exif data if exists. can't i just download the file with $http ?

Comment: Sure if you configure server to do what you are wanting. Have you confirmed that exif is removed?